# Mongodb cross compilation on linux for Raspberry Pi

Tags: cross-compilation, mongodb

I have raspberry pi model B. I want to build mongodb on my Linux system and want to copy build onto raspberry pi. 
I am using [mongo-non86](https://github.com/skrabban/mongo-nonx86) to build mongodb.

I have changed compilers to compile it with ***arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc*** and ***arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++***. But it gives error in between as below.

```
 build/linux2/normal/third_party/js-1.7/jscpucfg: 1: build/linux2/normal
/third_party/js-1.7/jscpucfg: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
 scons: *** [build/linux2/normal/third_party/js-1.7/jsautocfg.h] Error 2
```

So, my questions are,
1. How to solve this error?
2. Is there any alternate methodology for cross compiling on linux for Raspberry Pi.
3. What is third_party folder and js-1.7 contains (in mongodb build)?
4. Do I have to modify SConstruct file?

Note :- I have already referred this [link](http://scons.1086193.n5.nabble.com/HowTo-toggle-between-toolchains-during-scons-build-td32983.html), but didn't worked.

Comment: Have you considered installing it this way https://github.com/RickP/mongopi or http://c-mobberley.com/wordpress/index.php/2013/10/14/raspberry-pi-mongodb-installation-the-working-guide/

Comment: I am already following http://c-mobberley.com/wordpress/index.php/2013/10/14/raspberry-pi-mongodb-installation-the-working-guide/ for installing mongodb directly on R-Pi. I have tried https://github.com/RickP/mongopi but getting same error.

Comment: Unfortunately, still it is unsolved. Getting work done with compiling stuff once on raspberry pi. Then copy-paste compiled file 'mongod' to raspberry pi. After copy-paste, it requires some housekeeping mentioned in [this link](http://c-mobberley.com/wordpress/index.php/2013/10/14/raspberry-pi-mongodb-installation-the-working-guide/).

Comment: Compiling software is not really relevant to the Raspberry Pi, it is more OS specific. Please try on Ubuntu Stack. Compilation issues for WindowsIOT will need a new home too

Comment: IMHO atleast two arm based sources for MongoDB is available so definitely I cannot take normal ubuntu version of MongoDB and start compiling. Since, RPi is not having more processing power, easiest way is to cross compile using arm based gcc. FYKI it's working fine if you directly compile on RPI board.

Comment: RickP's version is only v2.1 and is over 4 yrs old. I think that skrabban's version is the same. Use the version in the Rasbian or Arch repos.

Answer (score 1):

Arch Linux for Pi has MongoDB v3+ in its repos I believe.

If you are staying with Rasbian, at least Jessie (not sure about Wheezy) has a version too but it is only v2.4

All you need to do is:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install mongodb
```

Then edit the config:

```
sudo nano /etc/mongodb.conf
```

Make sure you add the external IP address to the bind so it is accessible across your network (assuming you want that).

To check if it is running:

```
sudo systemctl status mongodb
```

To restart

```
sudo systemctl restart mongodb
```

Those last 2 commands are for Rasbian Jessie. For wheezy it would be:

```
sudo service mongodb restart
```